# Security function used is causing repainting pine script

Tags: pine-script

This is my sample script which is causing repainting once I refresh the chart. Not sure what's wrong with it.

**
//@version=5
strategy('MyTrendStrategy', overlay=true)

//f_security(_sym, _res, _src, _rep) => request.security(_sym, _res, _src)

f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
out1 = f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, "15", open)
out2 = f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close)

plot(out1, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
plot(out2, color=color.new(color.green, 0))

longCondition = ta.crossover(out2, out1)
if longCondition
strategy.entry('long', strategy.long, alert_message="GO LONG")
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(out2, out1)
if shortCondition
strategy.entry('short', strategy.short, alert_message="GO SHORT")
**

Answer (score 2):

this will sort you out. When using lookahead we need to use last bar info using the historical operator []. Otherwise it leaks future data on the historical set before it would have been possible in real world conditions.

```
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

For more info please see this [link](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Repainting.html#repainting-request-security-calls) and this [link](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Repainting.html#future-leak-with-request-security)

Cheers and best of luck with your coding and trading

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try that. does the same code works on Renko chart? I mean when we reference "close" in the script it gets the close based on chart type? or it will get only real candle close? if it gets only the closing price of normal candle price then should I get renko ticker and pass it to the security function.
Am I correct?

Comment: You can do that yes. The combination of renko and security is notorious for repainting however

Answer (score 0):

hi i put this but my alert not being triggered
res5 = input("D", type=input.resolution)

```
o = security(syminfo.tickerid, res5, open, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
c =security(syminfo.tickerid, res5, close[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

hz = security(syminfo.tickerid, res5, high, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
l = security(syminfo.tickerid, res5, low, barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).